# Temporary ban user feature in social media app mern stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, social-networking, mern

I'm working on project on social
Media website using mern stack.
I want to Implement feature of banning users temporary.
How can i implement this feature.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more property to the `User` Model (for example `banned: boolean`), and when the User tries to log-in, after you check if the credentials are good, check if he is banned or not. If he is not banned allow him to proceed, and if he is banned you can do something. (Of course, banning is a feature to implement for the `admin`)

Comment: I've implement admin panel. But then admin will have to change banned manually.is there any way that fields value can be changed automatically after specific time?

Comment: You can use `node-cron` package and create a function that will check for example each day (or each hour, or each minute...) if there is a User that is banned and that his banned period has expired, so you can unban him.